# Javascript multiple statements in a single if not working

Tags: javascript

I have 20 divs, each one with a speficif class, so I select it and check if is 1 of the 4 'special ones'.

The main issue is that the following code is supposed to work...

```
$('.cbp-ig-grid li, .cbp-ig-grid li a span object').on('click', function () {
        /* Variables Definition */
        var item = $(this).find('span').attr('class').split(' ')[1]
}


   if((item != 'item1') || (item != 'item2') || (item != 'item3') || (item != 'item4')){


// Always enters here!

}else{

    // Never enters here :(  (I need to enter here for the 4 cases in the if statement)

    }
```

but when I do for just one ... it works!

```
if(item != 'item1'){


// do stuff

}else{

    // do other stuff

    }
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please any help will be useful

Comment: yeah, it could be but it need to have it as a variable, and not make a selection again :/

Comment: Beside that, your Javascript doesnt look like valid. Missing one `}` and remove the `,` after finding your item.

Comment: sorry, I'll edit the post (it was a quick except of a real code)

Comment: Every possible string is either not `'item1'` or not `'item2'` or neither. Compare: every person in the world is either not Barack Obama or not Michelle Obama or neither. (Most people are neither.)

Comment: Please describe the expected behavior and what you actually observe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your if statement:

```
if((item != 'item1') || (item != 'item2') || (item != 'item3') || (item != 'item4')){

}
```

What that is saying is that if ANY of these conditions are true, the if condition is met and it will execute the if block.

Let's say the item is `"item2"` now the first expression of your if statement is met as it's not `item1` so that part is true. thus it executes the block.
What you want is: &&

```
if((item != 'item1') && (item != 'item2') && (item != 'item3') && (item != 'item4')){
    //when it's not the special case.
}
else
{ 
   //the 4 special cases.
}
```

Comment: yes, so that is correct, as per his code example, the else will happen when it's one of the special cases. "// Never enters here :(  (I need to enter here for the 4 cases in the if statement)"

Comment: yeah you are right, I missed that so I deleted my comment

Answer (score 2):

```
if((item != 'item1') || (item != 'item2') || (item != 'item3') || (item != 'item4')){
```

No chance to go into the else here... `item` is *always* different from one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

`.hasClass()` is your best friend. https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

```
$('.cbp-ig-grid li, .cbp-ig-grid li a span object').on('click', function () {
    /* Variables Definition */
    var item = $(this).find('span');

    switch(true) {
        case item.hasClass('item1'):
            // item 1
        break;

        case item.hasClass('item2'):
            // item 2
        break;

        case item.hasClass('item3'):
            // item 3
        break;

        case item.hasClass('item4'):
            // item 4
        break;

        default:
            // other stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's make it simple

```
if((item != 'item1') || (item != 'item2') || (item != 'item3') || (item != 'item4'))
```

Let's test it:

1:

```
item = 'item1':
false || true || true || true
that equals to true; because false || true = true
```

2:

```
item = 'theGreatOldOnes'
true || true || true || true - that equal to true
```

Both are true! That means that your expression is flawed - it doesn't make difference between 'special class' and any 'nonspecial class'

To make it understand difference between 'special' and 'not special' you need to use:

```
if((item != 'item1') && (item != 'item2') && (item != 'item3') && (item != 'item4'))
```

Or

```
if((item === 'item1') || (item === 'item2') || (item === 'item3') || (item === 'item4'))
```

You can do testing with 'item1' and 'theGreatOldOnes' to get a better grip on those things ^ ^